# Timelike curves in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I have a question that probably might sound silly to most of you.

We know that a natural Lorentz-invariant parametrization of a timelike curve is provided by:
$$\tau$$

the Lorentz-invariant [proper time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) along the curve.

Directly after this statement is implied the following:

$$cd\tau ~=~\sqrt{-ds^2}$$

My question is why are the other 3 terms dropped? Is it because since it is timelike $$dx , dy, dz$$ are dropped or set to zero? Or is it for some other reason?

Please do excuse me if you think this is silly but sometimes one stumbles over the very basics!

Comment: Which other three terms? Note that, in the metric, it is $\mathrm{d}t^2 + \mathrm{d}x^i\mathrm{d}x_i$, **not** $\mathrm{d}\tau$.

Comment: Oh right! Then how can one explain $$ cd\tau=\sqrt{-ds^2}$$?

Comment: This is a lorentz invariant/space-time metric, whose value is same for all inertial observers regardless of their motion. Imagine an observer who is travelling at such a speed that he is travelling from event a to event b, in his frame the spatial difference between the two events is 0. so they happen only separated in time. which is also called proper time.Being time like is a different thing, if you have more time  separation than space separation between events in your frame, then it is said events are time like.It turns out that if two events are time like for one,they are for all frames

Comment: Oh I see, so what you're saying in my case, the events a and b are separated in time only, that's why we are only left with $$cd\tau$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the curve is a geodesic then in the coordinate system of an observer moving along the geodesic coordinate time and proper time are the same. That's because in the freely falling observer's coordinates $dx = dy = dz = 0$ and therefore $ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 = -c^2d\tau^2$. This makes proper time a natural way of parameterising the curve because it's just the freely falling observer's coordinate time.

For a more general time-like curve I'm not sure of this is still the case.

Comment: Everything works the same for a general timelike curve, proper time still records the time read by a comoving clock.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement John Rennie's answer, one can always perform a Lorentz transformation to a coordinate system such as the particle is at rest for a given time. It's called instantaneous rest frame (IRF). This frame changes point to point, unless the particle's velocity is constant. In such a frame, we have

$
ds^2 = -c^2d\tau^2,
$

where $\tau$ is the proper time. It's straightforward to show that

$
d\tau=\frac{1}{\gamma}dt=\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}dt.
$

Since in a IRF $v=0$, then

$
\frac{d\tau}{dt}=1.
$

It shows that proper time measures the time registered by a clock moving together with the particle.

In summary, we can always use $\tau$ as a parameter to any timelike curve, not only timelike geodesics. Although it seems to be physically more natural to be used in a timelike geodesic, it's conveniently used because it's analogous to the arc length parameter used in Euclidean curves, which facilitates a lot the calculations.

Comment: I think you mean we can use it to parameterize "any timelike curve, not just geodesic curves"

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I said. I don't see why we can't use $\tau$ to parameterize an arbitrary curve.

Comment: A lightlike curve needs an affine parameterization different than the local invariant interval because the latter is zero. A spacelike curve isn't tangent to a particle path even for a moment (unless the particle is going FTL), so only timelike curves agree with your post.

Comment: You're right, I see the problem now. I was thinking "Riemannianly". I'll edit it, thank you.